# How to access lifecycleScope of the host fragment from a custom view?

Tags: android, android-custom-view, kotlin-coroutines, coroutinescope

I need to use coroutines inside a custom view. After watching this [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BOHK_w09pVA&list=LLtmun-_5YYwElZNp-WwwhKg&index=4), I believe my best option is to use **lifecycleScope** as the coroutine scope, so that it will be automatically cancelled when lifecycleowner is destroyed.

However I don't seem to have access to lifecycleScope inside the custom view. According to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#lifecyclescope), we can either have access to it from a *lifecycle* object as `lifecycle.coroutineScope`or from a *lifecycleOwner* as `lifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope`. But custom view is not a lifecycle owner. So can I have access to lifecycleScope of the fragment somehow? Or if I can't, which coroutine context should I use instead?

Answer (score 17):

I solved this by implementing [LifecycleObserver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LifecycleObserver) interface. It was very well explained in lesson 4 of this [free course on Udacity](https://www.udacity.com/course/developing-android-apps-with-kotlin--ud9012) how to make lifecycle aware components with LifecycleObserver interface.

I registered the lifecycle of the fragment inside the fragment and inside the custom view, while I get the lifecycle, I used the lifecycle to grap lifecycleScope.

```
//Inside custom view
fun registerLifecycleOwner(lifecycle: Lifecycle){
    lifecycle.addObserver(this)
    scope = lifecycle.coroutineScope
}

//Inside fragment
binding.myCustomView.registerLifecycleOwner(lifecycle)
```

Then inside the custom view, I used it like:

```
scope.launch{ 
    //Do work
}
```

**EDIT**
If you don't need to make your custom view lifecycle aware, you can also simply pass the scope to your custom view from the activity/fragment

```
fun setScope(lifecycleScope: CoroutineScope) {
    scope = lifecycleScope
}
```