# Android Custom View - Audio Player using Exoplayer

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, android-custom-view, exoplayer2.x

I am trying to make a custom view for playing audio in my app. This custom view should be used anywhere like activity, fragment, or list items. The given code is working but I want to optimize it to avoid memory leaks by using the best practices. In the layout, there is a button and slider. I am using google mdc for the slider .

Issue with the MDC slider : Values got from the exoplayer are of type Long. But slider accepts only float values.When converting the float values to long to show the progress, toFloat() giving -ve values.So i m using .toInt().toFloat().How to optimize it?

Issue with runOnUiTThread : To update the slider progress i am using runOnuithread in which it takes current duration from exoplayer instance to show the progress. I need to optimise it because i am not sure how to kill this runOnuithread once the view is not visible.I have tried using .post{} and postDelayed{} but the code inside them just worked only for one time.

Please help to optimize the given code.

```
class AudioPlayer(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : ConstraintLayout(context, attrs) {
    val actionButton: AppCompatImageView
    val slider: Slider
    var playerState = AudioPlayerState.Stop

    var media: String = ""

    var player: SimpleExoPlayer? = null

    var mediaItem: MediaItem? = null

    val mHandler = Handler()


    enum class AudioPlayerState {
        Played, Stop
    }

    init {
        inflate(context, R.layout.layout_audio_player, this)
        actionButton = findViewById(R.id.iv_play)
        slider = findViewById(R.id.seek)
        initPlayer()
        actionButton.setOnClickListener {
            if (playerState == AudioPlayerState.Stop) {
                playMedia()
            } else if (playerState == AudioPlayerState.Played) {
                stopMedia(false)
            }
        }

    }

    override fun onDetachedFromWindow() {
        stopMedia(true)
        release()
        super.onDetachedFromWindow()
    }

    private fun initPlayer() {
        player?.addListener(object : Player.EventListener {
            override fun onPlayerError(error: ExoPlaybackException) {
                super.onPlayerError(error)
                Log.e("hhp Player error", "Error $error")
            }

            override fun onPlaybackStateChanged(state: Int) {
                super.onPlaybackStateChanged(state)
                if (state == ExoPlayer.STATE_ENDED) {
                    stopMedia(true)
                }
            }
        })

    }

    private fun stopMedia(reset: Boolean) {
        actionButton.loadImageWithResId(R.drawable.ic_play)
        playerState = AudioPlayerState.Stop
        player?.playWhenReady = false

    }

    private fun playMedia() {
        actionButton.loadImageWithResId(R.drawable.ic_baseline_pause_24)
        playerState = AudioPlayerState.Played
        player?.playWhenReady = true


    }

    fun release() {
        player?.stop()
        player?.release()
        Log.e("hhp player", "released")
    }

    fun setMediaUrl(url: String) {
        media = url
        player = SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(context).build()
        player?.setMediaItem(MediaItem.fromUri(url))
        player?.playWhenReady = false
        player?.prepare()
        slider.value = 0F
        slider.addOnChangeListener { slider, value, fromUser ->
            if (fromUser) {
                player?.seekTo(value.toInt().toLong())
            }
        }
        (context as? Activity)?.runOnUiThread(object : Runnable {
            override fun run() {
                try {
                    slider.valueTo = player?.duration?.toInt()?.toFloat() ?: 100F
                    val mCurrentPosition = player?.currentPosition?.toInt()?.toFloat()
                    if (mCurrentPosition != null) {
                        if (mCurrentPosition >= slider.valueFrom && mCurrentPosition <= slider.valueTo)
                            slider.value = mCurrentPosition
                        if (slider.value == slider.valueTo) {
                            player?.stop()
                            stopMedia(true)
                        }
                    }


                    mHandler.postDelayed(this, 10)

                } catch (e: Exception) {

                }

            }
        })

    }
}
```

layout used in custom view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/exoplayerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/cv_audio"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_audio"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#234B92"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_play"
                android:layout_width="28dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_play"
                app:tint="@color/white" />

            <com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
                android:id="@+id/seek"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:value="0.0"
                android:valueFrom="0.0"
                android:valueTo="100.0"
                app:labelBehavior="gone"
                app:thumbColor="@color/white"
                app:trackColorActive="@color/white"
                app:trackColorInactive="@color/ash" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Is there any way to avoid using runOnuithread? Because if this custom view  is used in any item of recycler view or a viewpager this thread will continue to work till its activity ends?

Please help to optimise it with the best practice.

Comment: Are you using kotlin coroutines in this project?

Comment: yes,i am using coroutines @OyaCanli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, quick suggestions:
-If you're gonna use handler.postDelayed recursively, you should call `mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)` when view is destroyed/player is stopped
-I think 10 milliseconds interval for updating the slider is unnecessarily too short, it will have a cost on performance. Consider choosing a more reasonable interval.

Other than that, I would suggest implementing [LifecycleObserver](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle) to make this custom view lifecycle-aware. As a media player needs to react to callbacks like onPause/onStop/onDestroy, this could facilitate dealing with those states. Besides, when you implement this, you can also access to the lifecycleScope of the lifecycleOwner that you're observing(activity or fragment). You'd update the slider inside this scope, and it would be automatically cancelled when the host fragment/activity is destroyed. You can also pass the lifecycleScope to the custom view without implementing LifecycleObserver, but I think in your case, it is worth implementing it.

For more information about passing the lifecyclescope to the custom view, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64046621/9758208)

And with coroutines, your runnable who updates the slider could turn into something like this:

```
lifecycleScope.launchWhenResumed {
       while((slider.value < slider.valueTo)){
          //Update UI
          delay(yourDelayInterval)
       }
       //Stop player etc
}
```